# While applying for an Australia working holiday visa, it says passport information is wrong

Tags: passports, australia, e-visas

[image]I'm currently trying to apply for my working holiday visa for Australia and I can't even get past the 3rd page due to it saying my passport information is wrong, even though it's all typed in correctly and all the numbers are correct. I have checked numerous times and can't find out why it won't let me continue. I checked "no" on having done the health exam because I'm currently waiting to get it in a few days. Is that my issue? Is anyone also able to help me find my referral letter for the health exam?

Comment: Try contacting [ImmiAccount Technical Support](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/help-support/departmental-forms/online-forms/immiaccount-technical-support-form)

Comment: Does it not highlight the input(s) which cause a problem? Are dates in the right format? (They probably want dd/mm/yyyy, not mm/dd/yyyy) Did you make sure there’s no confusion between O and 0 or 1 and I or 5 and S for instance?

Comment: Can you tell us the field you get an error on and the exact error message? A screenshot (with your personal info masked) would help.

Comment: It does not highlight anything that it claims is wrong. I do have the dates in the correct order it wants as well. I also made sure that 0 and Os are the right ones as well.

Comment: This error is not saying there's something wrong with your passport, it's saying you aren't eligible to apply at this time.  What is your country of citizenship, and are you aged between 18 and 30 years old?

Comment: Yes I am currently 19

Comment: Is this your first working holiday visa or 2nd?

Comment: Was your passport issued by an eligible country or jurisdiction?